# Consultas relacionadas laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una consulta creada a varias tablas relacionadas que funciona correctamente pero me acabo de topar con el siguiente problema.

Voy a simplificar bastante la consulta

Con este código puedo ir filtrando los resultados a diferentes tablas:

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%');



 if($porcargar == true){
     $viajes = $viajes->where('estado','like', '0');

 }

 if($pordescargar == true){
     $viajes = $viajes->where('estado','like', '1');
 }


$viajes = $viajes->whereHas('direccionescar', function($query) use ($from, $to) {$query->whereBetween('fechacar', [$from, $to]);});

$viajes = $viajes->paginate(100);
```

Los filtros $porcargar y $pordescargar hacen referencia a la misma tabla y a la misma columna y la problemática viene cuando intento mostrar resultados que tengan como valor '0' o '1' en la columna 'estado' de la tabla 'viajes'.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%');



 if($porcargar == true){
     $viajes = $viajes->where('estado','like', '0');
     if($pordescargar == true){
     $viajes = $viajes->where('estado','like', '0')
                      ->orwhere('estado','like', '1');
    }

 }

 if($pordescargar == true){
     $viajes = $viajes->where('estado','like', '1');
     if($porcargar == true){
     $viajes = $viajes->where('estado','like', '1')
                      ->orwhere('estado','like', '0');

    }
}


$viajes = $viajes->whereHas('direccionescar', function($query) use ($from, $to) {$query->whereBetween('fechacar', [$from, $to]);});

$viajes = $viajes->paginate(100);
```

El problema es que si la variables $porcargar y $pordescargar están a true a la vez  la consulta no tiene en cuenta los otros dos filtros y muestra todos los registros con valor '0' o '1'. Sin embargo si solo una de as variables esa activada si que aplica los otros dos filtros.

Comment: cuando las dos condiciones se cumplen estás poniendo ` $viajes->where('estado', '0')->orwhere('estado', '1');`, entonces, te va a devolver todos los registros que tengan cualquiera de esos estados. ¿Podrías explicar que debería pasar si $porcargar y $pordescargar son verdaderos?

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ Cuando añado el orwhere la consulta no tiene en cuenta la consulta anterior, where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%'); ni la consulta posterior whereHas('direccionescar', function($query)........

Comment: Lo que me parece es que sí las puede estar teniendo en cuenta, pero por ejemplo, si los viajes tienen solo esos dos estados y no son nullables, cuando le pones where(estado 0) orWhere(estado 1), te va a traer todo, pisando las otras queries

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ Los viajes pueden tener mas estados pero no pueden ser nul. Como puedo resolverlo? No entiendo porque al introducir un orwhere en una de las consultas eso haga que se "salte" las otras.

Comment: ok, para escribir una respuesta, me gustaría saber si las variables `$porcargar` y `$pordescargar` también tienen asignado el valor `false`, o solo están presentes cuando son `true`

Comment: [así](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping) restringes un orWhere.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ Los valores de  $porcargar y $pordescargar pueden ser true o false también.

Answer (score 1):

Solo por no confundir las variables, voy definir la variable sobre la que construiré la consulta como `$query` y le voy a ir agregando las demás sentencias de la consulta a esta misma variable.
Por último le asignaré el valor a la variable `$viajes` al ejecutar la query con paginate.

Si tienes asignado también el valor `false` a las variables `$porcargar` y `$pordescargar`, puedes probar esto:

```
$query = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%');

$query->whereHas('direccionescar', function($query) use ($from, $to) {
    $query->whereBetween('fechacar', [$from, $to]);
});


if($porcargar === true && $pordescargar === false) {
    $query->where('estado', '0');
}

if($porcargar === false && $pordescargar === true) {
    $query->where('estado', '1');
}

if($porcargar === true && $pordescargar === true) {
    $query->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('estado', '0')
              ->orWhere('estado', '1');
    });
}

$viajes = $query->paginate(100);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente